# How to catch mouse moves outside of screen boundaries

Tags: winapi, mouse

My application catpures mouse on down event and relies on mouse movements not directly related to current mouse pointer position (visible pointer). So the math is based on initial point and the relative point of the mouse and has the visual feedback visually not linked to the visible mouse pointer so the pointer might as well be hidden completely. But when I reach the screen boundaries, the incoming coordinates are clipped. It looks reasonable since the pointer don't move either, but I would like to continue getting information about relative mouse movements even if the visible pointer reached the screen boundary. Is this possible? Maybe with access to raw mouse information from the driver?

Comment: Normally, you do this by reseting the mouse cursor position to the center of the window continually.

Comment: @Jan_Dvorak, looks like this can work, although I see that I have to recalculate coordinates coming from WM_MOUSEMOVE if I continually resetting the position with SetCursorPos in the same message handler

Answer (score 0):

Basically [Raw Input Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418864%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) serves my goal. One needs to register the window with RegisterRawInputDevices and get WM_INPUT message. The incoming data passes relative mouse movements not limited by the screen boundaries.